# How to join and sum tables without losing data?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

`Select (t1.count+t2.count) as countTotal from t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.ID = t2.ID);`

I'm doing this on a much larger scale with many variables added together. The problem I'm getting is that if one of the IDs is not in one of the tables I'm combining, the whole row for that ID comes back blank. My goal is to sum the two tables together for the most part but if one of the rows is only in one table, how can I keep that data in the resulting query?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NZ()`:

```
Select nz(t1.count) + nz(t2.count) as countTotal
from . . .
```

This replaces the `NULL` values with `0` so the `+` works.  Otherwise it returns `NULL` if any value is `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you so much I can't believe how hard it was to find this answer! I'll try it out and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `ID` can be missing from either table, you'll need to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

If the row is missing from one table, `t1.count + t2.count` will return **Null**.

According to [the documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c), the default return value from `Nz` for when the value is Null is 0 or a zero-length string.  I prefer to write clearer code, so I specify the value.

```
SELECT Nz(t1.count, 0) + Nz(t2.count, 0) as countTotal
FROM t1
  FULL OUTER JOIN t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Unfortunately Access doesn't allow a FULL OUTER JOIN, anyway to remedy this without rewriting all of my code?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar and ended up exporting it all to excel and carefully combining the data manually, it took me like 4 hours. That was only for 1200 records though, and I was working with 5 tables that all had different names for the  matching columns, huge mess.
Maybe you could try using a make table query, but if you have a large amount of fields then this isn’t feasible, and I’m not 100% it would even work.
The next best option would be to export the tables and import them into an SQL IDE that supports full outer join. Then make a table with that full join and export it back to Access. This would definitely work. But it can be tricky to import tables to an SQL IDE, I’ve had trouble with it in the past. But once I got them imported, it was smooth sailing.